# Devise login based on status of the User?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Devise gem for authentication. In my users table there is a status column for active and inactive status. What i want to do is something of type in application controller:

```
before_filter :check_user_status  

def check_user_status  
  if @current_user.status == "inactive"  
  #destroy user session  
  redirect_to new_session_path  
end
```

User will be able to access any controller if he is active otherwise he should be redirected to login page. I want this to be in application controller so that check_user_status be executed first before any controller action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check out the `active_for_authentication?` method to realize this. Look at the [documentation](http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Authenticatable) to find out more details and an example.